# Does main have a return address, dynamic link or return value in C?

Tags: c, stack, program-entry-point, activation-record

According to our book, each function has an activation record in the run-time stack in C. Each of these activation records has a return address, dynamic link, and return value. Does main have these also?

Answer (score 6):

All of these terms are purely implementation details - C has no notion of "return addresses" or "dynamic links."  It doesn't even have a notion of a "stack" at all.  Most *implementations* of C have these objects in them, and in those implementations it is possible that they exist for `main`.  However, there is no requirement that this happen.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you disassemble functions you will realize that most of the time the stack doesn't even contain the return value - often times the EAX register does (intel x86).
You can also look up "calling conventions" - it all pretty much depends on the compiler.
C is a language, how it's interpreted into machine code is not 'its' business.

Answer (score 1):

While this depends on the implementation, it is worthy looking at a C program compiled with gcc. If you run `objdump -d executable`, you will see it disassembled and you can see how `main()` behaves. Here's an example:

`08048680 <_start>:
 ...
 8048689:   54                      push   %esp
 804868a:   52                      push   %edx
 804868b:   68 a0 8b 04 08          push   $0x8048ba0
 8048690:   68 30 8b 04 08          push   $0x8048b30
 8048695:   51                      push   %ecx
 8048696:   56                      push   %esi
 8048697:   68 f1 88 04 08          push   $0x80488f1
 804869c:   e8 9f ff ff ff          call   8048640 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 80486a1:   f4                      hlt
 ...
080488f1 <main>:
 80488f1:   55                      push   %ebp
 80488f2:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80488f4:   57                      push   %edi
 80488f5:   56                      push   %esi
 80488f6:   53                      push   %ebx
 ...
 8048b2b:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048b2c:   5e                      pop    %esi
 8048b2d:   5f                      pop    %edi
 8048b2e:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048b2f:   c3                      ret`

You can see that main behaves similarly to a regular function in that it returns normally. In fact, if you look at the [linux base](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html) documentation, you'll see that the call to `__libc_start_main` that we see from `_start` actually requires `main` to behave like a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, `main()` is written just like a function, but isn't one. For example, it isn't allowed to call `main()`, it has *several* possible prototypes (can't do that in C!). Whatever is `return`ed from it gets passed to the operating system (and the program ends).

Individual C implementations might handle `main()` like a function called from "outside" for uniformity, but nobody forces them to do so (or disallow switching to some other form of doing it without telling anybody). There are traditional ways of implementing C, but nobody is forced to do it that way. It is just the simplest way on our typical architectures.

Comment: There is no such language as "C/C++". In C, calling `main` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @R, it isn't. It _usually_ works (many funny oneliners exploit this), but it isn't allowed by the standard at all.

Comment: Yes it is. You're confusing C and C++. C++ forbids calling `main` because they allow for implementations where global ctors are implemented via special code injected at the beginning of `main` (the traditional cfront approach). C places no restrictions on `main`. It's an ordinary function with external linkage and thus it's legal to call it unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @R, please show me where the standard says this. It was beaten into me from my K&R days that this is forbidden, and that predates C++ by a fair bit. I also dimly remember that under MS-DOS it didn't work, as the calling convention for `main()` was completely different.

Comment: The only specification of the `main` function is in 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup and 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination. Neither places any restriction on calling `main`, and in the latter, the phrase "the initial call to the main function" is used, making it clear that other invocations of `main` could exist.